# Remote Desktop Connection, 2 layers + Dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

So I'm having to work late tomorrow night and I'm wanting to be able to remote into my work computer and be able to use dual monitors as I normally would AT work. The problem is I can't remote directly to my work computer, government firewall/privacy stuff. So I have to open a Remote Desktop Connection to a "terminal server", virtual Win7 box, then open another Remote Desktop connection to my actual computer.

Anyways, I can get the first layer "terminal server" to display on both monitors, but when I make the second connection, I only get one. Is there something other than the "Use all my monitors for the remote session" checkbox?

All machines involved are win7 professional.

Comment: The number of monitors may be limited in group policy, something to check at least: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 Professional does not support Multi-Monitor RDP. [Only Enterprise and Ultimate do.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remote-desktop-connection-faq#1TC=windows-7)

The Spanning feature works somewhat different: It simulates a single large monitor, as opposed to multiple monitors.

Comment: Yea, I knew it was only available on those two editions. What threw me is the the "terminal server" is a virtual machine running what I believe to be 7 pro on a Server 2008 physical box.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
mstsc.exe /span
```

should open a Remote Desktop session using all available space. This seems to work differently to the "Use all my monitors for the remote session" checkbox. I can't vouch for it working under your particular circumstances, though.